# second axis label is to big when using multiple figure panel

Tags: r

I am using standard R graphs and create a figure with two axis.
Everything is fine until I try to plot `par(mfrow=c(4,3))`. The label on the right side is always a bit to big... When I plot `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` everything looks fine.

```
new_cex <- .75
pdf(file='jnk.pdf', width=11.69, height=8.27)
par(mfrow=c(4,3), mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
for(i in 1:12) {
  x <- runif(10)
  y1 <- runif(10)
  y2 <- runif(10)

  plot(1, type="n", xlim=range(x), bty="n", axes=F, cex.lab=new_cex,
       ylim=range(pretty(range(y1))), xlab="Time (hours)", ylab="ABC")
  axis(1, at=x, labels=round(x,2), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  axis(side=2, at=pretty(range(y1)), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  points(x, y1, lwd=2)
  lines(lowess(x, y1), lwd=6)
  par(new=TRUE)
  plot(1, type="n", axes=F, bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y2))
  axis(side=4, at=pretty(range(y2)), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  mtext("CDE",side=4,line=3, cex=new_cex)
  points(x, y2, col=2, lwd=2)
  lines(lowess(x, y2), col=2, lwd=6, lty=2)
}

dev.off()
```

I used a global `new_cex` variable and I figured out that in case of `mfrow=c(4,3)` the label is always a bit bigger. So in general it is changing...

Maybe someone can give it a try, maybe it is a versioning thing... By changing the 3 row to `mfrow=c(1,1)`, all axis labels will have the same size...

Comment: I tried it the other way by leaving the `cex` settings as they are and wanted to multiply the `cex` within `text` by `0.83` but actually this is not enough... When I multiply it by `*.65` it looks ok. But still don't get it. `par` should change it globally!

Comment: So changing it to `mtext("CDE",side=4,line=3, cex=new_cex * 0.65)` looks ok... But I have to change this back to one in case I use `mfrow=c(1,1)`... Not the best solution... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help of `mtext` clearly states that cex is not scaled according to `par(mfrow=c(4,3))` :

> cex
>   character expansion factor. NULL and NA are equivalent to 1.0.
>   This is an absolute measure, not scaled by par("cex") or by setting
>   par("mfrow") or par("mfcol"). Can be a vector.

To fix this, store the original `cex`, than measure the reduction ratio after changing `par(mfrow)`, and use it in `mtext`, i.e. :

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1)) # to restore original cex and layout
new_cex <- .75
originalCex <- par("cex")
par(mfrow=c(4,3), mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
originalCexReduced <- par("cex")
cexRatio <- originalCexReduced / originalCex
for(i in 1:12) {
  x <- runif(10)
  y1 <- runif(10)
  y2 <- runif(10)

  plot(1, type="n", xlim=range(x), bty="n", axes=F, cex.lab=new_cex,
       ylim=range(pretty(range(y1))), xlab="Time (hours)", ylab="ABC")
  axis(1, at=x, labels=round(x,2), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  axis(side=2, at=pretty(range(y1)), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  points(x, y1, lwd=2)
  lines(lowess(x, y1), lwd=6)
  par(new=TRUE)
  plot(1, type="n", axes=F, bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y2))
  axis(side=4, at=pretty(range(y2)), cex.axis=new_cex, las=2)
  mtext("CDE",side=4,line=3, cex=new_cex*cexRatio)
  points(x, y2, col=2, lwd=2)
  lines(lowess(x, y2), col=2, lwd=6, lty=2)
}
```

`cexRatio` is `0.66`, as more or less you noticed.

Comment: Awesome solution... This forum is great! Don't like the comments I have to write so other people can understand what happens in the code, but at least it is solid!

Comment: @drmariod: well, people can't read your mind and sometimes is difficult to understand what happens in the code. But you provided a reproducible code and this is really appreciated and greatly helps other people to give you solutions ;)

Comment: besides the typo with `y` instead of `y1` :-)